# show progress of yfinance historical data to tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, progress-bar, yfinance

im still new to programming and Im trying to create a tkinter app for my other hobby which is trading. I usually download the historical data I need from yfinance and my question is as to how I can display the download progress to my tkinter app.. I heard about the ttk.Progressbar but I dont know how to implement it during the download. Basically what I want to happen is to have the progressbar move while the script is downloading the historical data... hope someone can help. if the question is too confusing let me know so I can clarify it thanks

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import yfinance as yf


class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        download_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Download", command=self.download)
        download_button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="EW")

        progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=100, mode="determinate")
        progress_bar.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def download(self):
        stocks = ["tsla", "aapl", "amzn", "fb", "ko"]

        df = yf.download(stocks, period='3y')

        df.to_csv("File.csv")


root = Main()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _I heard about the ttk.Progressbar but I dont know how to implement it during the download._ Have you consulted the relevant documentation? This is likely off-topic, please see [help/on-topic], [ask].

Comment: hi @AMC thanks for your reply to my question... I don't really know if this is off-topic or not but as I understand it, for the determinate mode, I will need to measure the progress of the said download and I guess my better question is how to measure it so when the "yf.download(stocks, period='3y')" run, the progress bar will move to 20% if 1st stock is downloaded, 40% once 2nd stock is downloaded, etc..

Comment: Basically you cannot update progress bar if using `yf.download(stocks, ...)`.  You can use `yf.Ticker(stock).history(...)` for each stock in the stock list and update progress bar after getting history of a stock.